# CakePHP - How to use connectNamed right?

Tags: cakephp

I can't figure out how I can write this right to get 'cat' and 'city' as $this->params['named'] within my controller:

```
Router::connect('/this-is-a-simple-url', array('controller' => 'listings', 'action' => 'search', 'cat' => 200, 'city' => 57));
```

I tried to place Router::connectNamed(array('cat', 'city')); before that rule, but this is not changing anything.

Please help me out!
Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

you mean like:

```
Router::connect('/this-is-a-simple-url', 
    array(
       'controller' => 'listings', 
       'action' => 'search', 
       array(
           'named'   => array(      
               'cat'  => '[a-Z]+',
               'city' => '[\d]+'
           )
       )
   )
);
```

Comment: Hi, in this special case, I have a static cat and a static city ID to give with the URL. I am building special landing pages. So I need to redirect to the given cat and city ID. In you case, everything is located in 'pass' and not directly as 'named'.